# Nodejs dns resolve timeout

Tags: node.js, dns

I have a nodejs script which is looping threw multiple wifi routers.

I am using the package `node-wifi` to establish a connection.

The problem is that when calling `wifi.connect` once it resolved I can not directly send a request on the local network, seems that it needs a little more time to be operative, if I am running the request directly I have a `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

So I created this little function to wait until the connection is well established

```
const wifi = require("node-wifi");
const dns = require('dns');
const debug = require('debug')('wifi');

const canResolve = host => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!host) host = 'google.com';
    debug(`Intenting to resolve host ${host} to verify connection`)
    dns.resolve(host, err => {
        if (err) {
            debug(`Fail to resolve host ${host} with error ${err}`)
            return resolve(false);
        }
        resolve(true);
    })
})

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

const waitForConnection = (maxRetry, host, retry) => {
    if (!retry) retry = 0;
    if (retry >= maxRetry) return Promise.reject(new Error('Can not connect to internet'))

    return sleep(1000)
        .then(() => canResolve(host))
        .then(connected => {
            if (connected) {
                debug(`WIFI connection verificated`);
                return;
            }
            retry++;
            return waitForConnection(maxRetry, host, retry)
        })
}
```

But from time to time (70% of the cases aprox) I have the error `Fail to resolve host 192.168.169.1 with error Error: queryA ETIMEOUT 192.168.169.1` until `maxRetry` is reached.
`192.168.169.1` is the host variable defined and the ip of my router.

while `dns.resolve` is working I am running the following script on another process

```
require('dns').resolve('192.168.169.1', function(err){console.log(err)})
```

And I instantaneously have a response with no error.

So I do not really understand why on a process I have a timeout and on another process I have an instant success response.

On another way I am open for improvements, the dns resolve is maybe not the better way to wait for the connection to be 100% functional. I could do it a much more easier way with a timeout of 5s for example but this is not very clean